# JMenu setDelay() pop down delay

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenupopup

In my application, I have a JPopupMenu that displays a set of sub-menus:

```
private static JMenu createMenu(String title) {
    JMenu menu = new JMenu(title);
    menu.setDelay(2000);
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("123"));
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("234"));
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("345"));
    return menu;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
    final JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPopupMenu jpm = new JPopupMenu();
            jpm.add(createMenu("XXX"));
            jpm.add(createMenu("YYY"));
            jpm.add(createMenu("ZZZ"));
            jpm.show(button, 0, 0);
        } 
    });

    frame.add(button);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
}
```

This application usually runs on Windows.

I first mouse-over the first XXX sub-menu. Sometimes, I accidentally move my mouse over YYY, which then causes the first sub-menu to disappear immediately.

From reading the Javadoc, it would seem that calling JMenu.setDelay(2000) should suggest that the JMenu's popup menu wait 2 seconds before popping down. However, it only seems to delay the next menu 2 seconds before popping up.

Is there a way to delay the pop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Here's something interesting; from [Bug #6563939 *Delay should be respected before hiding a JMenu*, open since 2007](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6563939)

> Javadoc might be misleading in this
> point. It says "before submenus are
> popped up or down". "Popping down"
> could be understood as "hiding", but
> it rather has the meaning of "submenu
> is rendered below his parent menu".

---

It also [seems to suggest that this depends on the L&F you're using](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#setDelay%28int%29), so it looks like more like something you can only request or hint at:

> Each look and feel (L&F) may determine
> it's own policy for observing the
> delay property. In most cases, the
> delay is not observed for top level
> menus or while dragging. This method
> is a property of the look and feel
> code and is used to manage the
> idiosyncracies of the various UI
> implementations.

Comment: @Huey I've updated my answer with a link to a bug that seems to point out this very issue, open since 2007

Comment: I suppose if you really wanted the delay, you could extend `JMenu` and do something tricky there - although I took a look at the source for `JMenu` and there doesn't seem to be a straight-forward way to do it